# Problema de SQL

Tags: sql

Preciso criar um SQL que mostre os números de cadastro dos colaboradores de uma tabela, seus nomes e a quantidade de pessoas dependentes dos colaboradores que tenham mais do que um dependente, ordenando o resultado em ordem decrescente pela quantidade de dependentes.

Fiz o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT c.numCad,
c.nomFun,
(SELECT COUNT (d.numCad) FROM dependentes d AS contDep WHERE d.numCad = c.numCad 
HAVING contDep > 1) qtDep
FROM colaboradores c
ORDER BY qtDep DESC;
```

Pórem sinto que estas linhas apresentam um erro:

```
(SELECT COUNT (d.numCad) FROM dependentes d AS contDep WHERE d.numCad = c.numCad HAVING contDep > 1) qtDep
```

E estou sem ideias do que fazer a respeito.

O problema requisita que o numCad seja *primary key* da tabela `colaboradores` e *foreign key* da tabela `dependentes`.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT      c.numCad
        ,   c.nomFun
        ,   qtDep.dependentes
FROM        colaboradores c
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      numCad
                        ,   COUNT(1) AS dependentes
                FROM        dependentes
                GROUP BY    numCad
                HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
            ) qtDep ON qtDep.numCad = c.numCad
ORDER BY    qtDep.dependentes
```